# Why doesn't this code get the URL from Safari?

Tags: javascript, browser, safari, safari-extension, browser-extension

I am creating a safari extension. When the user right-clicks on a link in safari, it should bring up the context menu. When the user clicks on "Get URL", it should open the clicked on url in a new window. I can't figure out how to get the url! It always opens "not found" instead.

`injected.js` :

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', handleContextMenu, false);

function handleContextMenu(event) 
{
    var target = event.target;
    while(target != null && target.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE && target.nodeName.toLowerCase() != "a") 
    {
        target = target.parentNode;
    }

    if(target.href)
    {
        safari.self.tab.setContextMenuEventUserInfo(event, target.href);
    }
    else
    {
        var foo = "href not found";
        safari.self.tab.setContextMenuEventUserInfo(event, foo);
    }  
}
```

`Global.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<script>
var lastUrl;

safari.application.addEventListener("contextmenu",handleContextMenu,false);
safari.application.addEventListener('command', handleCommand, false);

function handleContextMenu(event) 
{
    var query = event.userInfo;
    lastUrl = query;

    event.contextMenu.appendContextMenuItem("getUrl", "Get URL");
}

function handleCommand(event) 
{
    if(event.command === 'getUrl') 
    {
        if (lastUrl) 
        {
            safari.application.openBrowserWindow().activeTab.url = lastUrl;
        }
        else
        {
            safari.application.openBrowserWindow().activeTab.url = "not found";
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

**How do I get the url?** It always opens "not found" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have `var last url = event.userInfo` in the `handleCommand` function? The userInfo should be defined at that point, and it should be more predictable that trying to set the value on the contextmenu event.

Comment: Doesn't make any difference - "not found" is still the url that opens. I don't have any experience developing safari extensions, so I'm just blundering through.

Comment: Just so you know, this piece of code is an important part of a much bigger super useful project. If you can figure this out, you could be helping me solve a problem that could save people countless hours! XD

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why your code is not working, but there are a couple of things you might want to change anyway.

First, in the injected content script, if there's no target.href, don't bother calling safari.self.tab.setContextMenuEventUserInfo.

Second, in the global script, change your `handleContextMenu` function as follows:

```
function handleContextMenu(event) {
    if (event.userInfo) {
        event.contextMenu.appendContextMenuItem("getUrl", "Get URL");
    }
}
```

That way, if the user didn't right-click a link, the context menu item won't be inserted.

Third, as Matt said, you don't need the `lastUrl` global variable, unless it serves some other purpose. You can refer to event.userInfo directly in `handleCommand`. And you don't need to check whether it's empty, because the context menu will only be inserted by `handleContextMenu` if it's not.

```
function handleCommand(event) {
    if (event.command === 'getUrl') {
        safari.application.openBrowserWindow().activeTab.url = event.userInfo;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried what you said, and now "Get URL" doesn't even show up in the context menu. I tested it with even simple html file containing only an anchor in the body.

Comment: In that case there must be some mistake in one of the scripts. Here is a proof-of-concept extension that shows that the code works: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23990/Canisbos/Nothing.safariextz -- it does nothing but display the link's URL when you select Get URL in the context menu. You can extract the source code using the Terminal command `xar -xf Nothing.safariextz`.